# Elixir Ecto Insert empty belongs_to

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

First: I've found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770369/insert-null-into-ecto-belongs-to-field) but it does not work.

I have a relation between two models

```
Council(1)<->(n)Department
```

and I want to insert a council without a relation to a department.

I've got this ecto schema:

```
schema "councils" do
  field :name, :string
  field :description, :string
  belongs_to :department, Db2.Department
  many_to_many :students, Db2.Student, join_through: Db2.StudentCouncil
  many_to_many :periods, Db2.Period, join_through: Db2.StudentCouncil

  timestamps()
end
```

with this SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.councils
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('councils_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(255),
  description character varying(255),
  department_id integer,
  inserted_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT councils_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT councils_department_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
      REFERENCES public.departments (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

The documentation says that `cast/4` is deprecated, but phoenix created the changeset with `cast/3` & `validate_required/3` by itself. I only added the `department` so that I have the following changeset:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name, :description, :department_id])
  |> validate_required([:name])
  |> unique_constraint(:name)
  |> assoc_constraint(:department)
end
```

For the form I'am using the the default phoenix.html form elements.
When I submit the form phoenix says the following:

```
[debug] QUERY OK db=1.2ms queue=0.1ms
SELECT u0."id", u0."uid", u0."is_admin", u0."is_staff", u0."password_hash", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at" FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" = $1) [1]
[debug] Processing by Db2.CouncilController.create/2
Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "KwpdFCZ/bFN9fwkcXSAYLhRCIzgOAAAAXeoEa4+d1MoT7SvzZpgOdg==", "_utf8" => "✓", "council" => %{"department_id" => "", "description" => "", "name" => "test2"}}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[debug] QUERY OK db=1.2ms queue=0.1ms


#Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{description: "", name: "test2"},
  errors: [department_id: {"is invalid", [type: :id]}], data: #Db2.Council<>,
  valid?: false>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending an empty string as the `department_id` instead of `nil`. Empty strings are not cast to `nil` automatically:

```
iex(1)> MyApp.Post.changeset %MyApp.Post{}, %{"title" => "Hello"}
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{title: "Hello"}, errors: [],
 data: #MyApp.Post<>, valid?: true>
iex(2)> MyApp.Post.changeset %MyApp.Post{}, %{"title" => "Hello", "user_id" => nil}
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{title: "Hello"}, errors: [],
 data: #MyApp.Post<>, valid?: true>
iex(3)> MyApp.Post.changeset %MyApp.Post{}, %{"title" => "Hello", "user_id" => "1"}
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{title: "Hello", user_id: 1}, errors: [],
 data: #MyApp.Post<>, valid?: true>
iex(4)> MyApp.Post.changeset %MyApp.Post{}, %{"title" => "Hello", "user_id" => ""}
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{title: "Hello"},
 errors: [user_id: {"is invalid", [type: :id]}], data: #MyApp.Post<>,
 valid?: false>
```

You can either explicitly set `department_id` to `nil` before calling `changeset`, or use Phoenix's [`scrub_params`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#scrub_params/2) plug, which does the same thing for all empty strings:

```
# web/controllers/council_controller.ex
plug :scrub_params, "council" when action in [:create]
```

(Change `"council"` to the field name and `[:create]` to the list of actions where you're accepting that field.)

Comment: woOt? Thank you. Works like a charm :)